# timed bashed ( at ) runs but throws error

Tags: php, bash, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a command line app in which I need to implement some kind of scheduler to run a script once after execution of the first script.

Now, I'm trying to run a script a minute after execution time, with this directive:

```
$dir = getcwd().'/';

    exec('echo '.$dir.'./prices get:inventorylist '.database_connector::getUserId().' '.database_connector::getLand().' --reportId="'.$this->reportRequestId.'" | /usr/bin/at now + 1 min');
```

When trying to run this without `echo` and | `/usr/bin/at now + 1 min` it's running perfectly fine without throwing any errors, I've also checked if `at` is working, and it should be fine.

Well, actually, the script is getting executed after the given additional time, but I keep getting this error in syslog:

```
Jan 23 19:09:01 atd[6792]: Exec failed for mail command: No such file or directory.
```

I can't understand this error, as, as I mentioned above, the script is running and the directive is running without any problems or errors when I run it without at.

Is there something I don't see why this error could be possibly thrown?

Comment: Is `at` configured to send mail of output? Is there something wrong with the `at` configuration? Are you missing `/usr/sbin/sendmail` or something perhaps? Are you sure the task isn't running even when `at` gives that error?

Comment: No, the task is running, but I think you gave me the answer with the at mail configuration. I will have a look at this, I'm pretty sure this will be it. Thanks! @EtanReisner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing `/usr/sbin/sendmail` or something perhaps?

That error is `at` telling you it couldn't send mail with the output of the command it ran I believe.